# How do I get a proper answer and not just random numbers?

Tags: c++, terminal

As I said, I'm trying to make a political test and I made a test to make sure I can add axis' their value but it just gives me some random number instead of the desired answers. I am pretty new to C++ and tried to flex my function-creating muscles but probably messed something up. I tried a lot of things but it just won't work. If you can, please help me and tell me how to get a proper value.

```
#include <iostream>

int adding_value (int, int);

int main() {
    int x; //this was to be the answer of the user
    int y; //this was to be the axis that gets value added 
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "\n";
    int z = adding_value(x, y);
    std::cout << z << std::endl;

}

int adding_value (int x, int y) {

    switch (x) {
        case 1: {
            int y = y + 2;
            break; }
        case 2: {
            y++;
            break; }
        case 3: {
            break; }
        case 4: {
            y--;
            break; }
        case 5: {
            y = y - 2;
            break; }
    return y;
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you set `y`?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable `y`.

Comment: `int y = y + 2;` doesn't use your `y` parameter. you probably just get rid of `int y =` part.

Comment: there are 3 different variables called `y` in your code

Comment: @JohnFilleau: yes, it is legal. it exhibits UB, as it reads `y` before initialization. `void* p = &p;` is similar construct  without UB.

Comment: @Jarod yeah I had to look it up. Legal within a declared scope within a case. I had an error a few months back with trying to declare a variable in a case without the scoping braces.

Answer (score 1):

The first think you need to do is to enable your compiler warnings. If you had done that you would have seen:

> ```
> <source>: In function 'int main()':
>
> <source>:10:25: warning: 'y' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
>
>    10 |     int z = adding_value(x, y);
>
>       |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
>
> Compiler returned: 0
> ```

`y` is uninitialized. Accessing it leads to Undefined Behavior. You probably meant to read from `cin` into `y`.

---

> ```
> <source>:34:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
>
> }
> ```

---

> ```
> <source>:19:21: warning: variable 'y' is uninitialized when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
>
>             int y = y + 2;
>
>                 ~   ^
> ```

Comment: I had the warnings enabled and never received a warning about y being uninitialised and I did try initialising it (by that I mean I gave it the value 0) and it still just gives me the number 4196797 whenever I input 2

Comment: @potato where did you initialize it? In main? You have three variables named `y` in your program. The one in `main`, the one in `adding_value`'s prototype, and the one in your `case 1:`. The first is copied into the second. The third only exists within that `case` and then ceases to exist. So if you enter `case 1:` you're actually just returning whatever value of `y` you passed in. Rename them to `a`, `b`, and `c` to make it clearer if you still don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to initialise **y** before passing it as parameter to adding_value() function.

The random value of **y** passing through adding_value() function and some operations on **y** gives random value that's why you're getting random value.